# Find the standard matrix of the linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

> Suppose there is a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R^2}$ such that $$T\left( \begin{array}{ccc}2 \\ 1 \end{array}
>  \right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}1\\ 4 \end{array} \right)$$ and
>    $$T\left( \begin{array}{ccc}3 \\ 2 \end{array} \right)=\left(
>  \begin{array}{ccc}3 \\ 3 \end{array} \right)$$
>
> What is the standard matrix of $T$?

So I thought I could just solve the system:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 3 &|& 1 & 3\\
1 & 2 &|& 4 & 3\\ \end{array} \right)$$

to obtain:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 &|& -10 &-3\\
0 & 1 &|& 7 & 3\\ \end{array} \right)$$

and that the standard matrix would just be:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-10 &-3\\
7 & 3\\ \end{array} \right)$$

However, this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the standard matrix of $T$.  What we have is
$$
A \pmatrix{2&3\\1&2} = \pmatrix{1&3\\4&3}
$$
So, in fact, the answer to this question will be
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&3\\4&3}\pmatrix{2&3\\1&2}^{-1}
$$
The result you found was
$$
\pmatrix{-10 &-3\\
7 & 3\\} =
\pmatrix{2&3\\1&2}^{-1}\pmatrix{1&3\\4&3}
$$
which is a different matrix altogether.